# Solr dataimport from mdb index only first 10 records

Tags: ms-access, solr, lucene, dataimporthandler, ucanaccess

I have mdb databse file and I try to import it to Solr. The database file has more than 6000 records but it only index 10 records in Solr:

> Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 10 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
>   (Duration: 03s)

The logging output is just **warnings only:**

```
9/26/2014 4:36:52 PM
WARN
ManagedResource
No stored data found for /rest/managed
9/26/2014 4:36:52 PM
WARN
ManagedResource
No stored data found for /rest/managed
9/26/2014 4:36:52 PM
WARN
ManagedResource
No registered observers for /rest/managed
9/26/2014 4:36:52 PM
WARN
ManagedResource
No registered observers for /rest/managed
9/26/2014 4:37:07 PM
WARN
Index
unsupported collating sort order SortOrder[1025(0)] for text index,​ making read-only
9/26/2014 4:37:08 PM
WARN
Index
unsupported collating sort order SortOrder[1025(0)] for text index,​ making read-only
9/26/2014 4:37:10 PM
WARN
Index
unsupported data type BINARY for index,​ making read-only
```

I use the following in solrconfig.xml:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="solr.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">C:\solr-4.9.0\example\solr\fox\conf\data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

And this in data-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataConfig>
<dataSource driver="net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver" type="JdbcDataSource" url="jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/feqh/main.mdb;memory=false" />

<document>
    <entity name="Book" 
            query="select bkid AS id, bkid AS BookID,bk AS BookTitle from 0bok">
       <field column="id" name="id"/>
       <field column="BookID" name="BookID"/>
       <field column="BookTitle" name="BookTitle"/>
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I use UCanAccess driver becuase I have Java8 and jdbc-odbc driver is not supported (sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver) I thought that it may be due to memory limitation so I set `memory=false` to let it write on the disk. Is there any solutions or suggestions?

Comment: Try setting up a small stand-alone Java application that connects to the .mdb file via UCanAccess, executes the SQL query, and loops through the ResultSet counting the rows. That way you can confirm if UCanAccess can actually "see" more than 10 records. (There have been earlier reports where UCanAccess was unable to see all of the rows in a table due to some subtle corruption in the Access file's metadata. Doing a Compact and Repair on the .mdb file in Access was usually sufficient to resolve the problem.)

Comment: @GordThompson In order to apply your suggestion, I have installed an old version of Microsoft office that I had from several years ago (Office 2000) and I tried to open the file with Access 2000 and  I discovered that Access 2000 tell me that mdb file was created in older version and it told me to convert it to the current version! Before Access, I opened this file using MDB Viewer Plus and I found that Access shows more columns than it show. Now Access 2000 does not able to convert the file. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: How do you trigger the import? Probably via the admin GUI? If so, did you clear the values within "Start, Rows"? This is a common mistake :)

Comment: @cheffe Oh Yeah Man!!! :) But The values are disabled and If I had another life added to my current life,I would not able to figure this out! Now, How could I cancel start and end from this query?

Comment: @GordThompson good news about this issue: since the 2.0.9 UCanAccess can identify to the corruption issue and read all records.

Answer (score 0):

Since the 2.0.9 version, UcanAccess can read all the records even if the file is "corrupted"(I mean, whether it has the wrong row number in the table's metadata).
Also, in this kind of corruption, it will print a warning, confirming that your database is corrupted and suggesting the use of the repair tool.
So, in order to verify if your issue is due to a metadata's "corruption", you simply have  to upgrade your UCanAccess version and then see the logs.